# Combining OCSP Stapling and manual OCSP request from client

Tags: tls, openssl, ocsp

Currently, I have an implementation where I send an OCSP request in the `verify_callback(int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *x509_ctx)` function for every intermediate and end-entity certificate. The `verify_callback` function is set using the `SSL_CTX_set_verify()` function.

Now, I would like to add OCSP stapling to my implementation. I do have some example implementation of how to include OCSP Stapling using an OCSP callback.

The issue with adding the above OCSP callback is that the `verify_callback()` first gets called prior to OCSP Stapling callback function.

My question is how can I have both of them in such a way that, if there is no OCSP stapling response from the server, then the client will itself send the OCSP request.

Is there a way to check if the OCSP stapling is supported or not before we reach the `verify_callback()` function?

Comment: Why not simply check the OCSP status outside the verify callback but before exchanging data?

Comment: Welcome to Security.SE. This question seems to be more about the programming concept. Have you tried stackoverflow?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have tried stackOverflow. I haven't got a reply so far.

Comment: Steffen, How to check the OCSP status outside of verify_callback?

Comment: please do not cross-post - SO is the best place for this.